# web.xml configuration for restlet filter

Tags: google-app-engine, restlet

Is there any special configuration needed in web.xml for using org.restlet.routing.Filter? I have edited it as(same as javax.servlet.Filter):

```
<filter>
<filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>*myfilterclassname*</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Its not working & the response is "Source not available". Any more changes needed in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

A RESTLET filter is not a ServletFilter and cannot be used directly in a web.xml.
Filter are part of the routers package in RESTLET which are specialized Restlets that can have other Restlets attached to them and that can automatically delegate calls based on a URI template.

Comment: setup an application (http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html). When configuring a router, you can chain a filter in between.